# Edit table row using User Forms

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have this UserForm that adds data as a new row (TAB One ) and second TAB that deletes the wanted entry row or edits.

Table structure:
Column A  /  Column B  /  Column C  /  Column D

The thing is I managed to make the update button code that it would find a row based on text value from combobox, update UserForm fields, but the code that updates the row data seems to not work (it only updates the first cell in Column A)

VBA code:

```
Private Sub atnaujintiTiekeja_Click()  'UPDATE button code from userforms


  If Me.CMBpasirinktiTiekeja.Value = "" Then

  MsgBox "Prašome pasirinkti norimą atnaujinti tiekėją!", vbExclamation

  Exit Sub

  End If
 
 Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet
  Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("važtaraštis")  'sheet that uses the userform
  Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tiekėjai")  'sheet with data table that needs to be updated (it will be hidden)

   Dim tbl As ListObject
  Set tbl = ws1.ListObjects("tiekejuSarasas")
  Dim FoundCell As Range
  Dim LookupValue As String

 
 LookupValue = Me.CMBpasirinktiTiekeja.Value   'Me.CMBpasirinktiTiekeja.Value  is combobox value

 On Error Resume Next

  Set FoundCell = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Find(LookupValue, LookAt:=xlWhole)

  On Error GoTo 0
  If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then


 Dim rowNo As Double

  rowNo = FoundCell.Row - tbl.HeaderRowRange.Row


  '-------------------------------

  '--------------------------------

 
 With tbl.ListRows(rowNo)

  .Range(1).Value = Me.tiekejoPilnasPavadinimas.Text   'Column A

  .Range(2).Value = Me.tiekejoSutrumpintasPavadinimas.Text   'Column B

  .Range(3).Value = Val(Me.suteikiamaNuolaidaKoreguota.Value) / 100    'Column C

  .Range(4).Value = Val(Me.gaunamaNuolaidaKoreguota.Value) / 100    'Column D

  '-------------------------------------------

  '-------------------------------------------

  End With
  Else
  MsgBox "Value not found"
  End If
 

 Dim msg As String
  Dim ans As String


 msg = "Tiekėjas atnaujintas sėkmingai" & vbNewLine & "Ar norite pridėti naują tiekėjà?"

  Unload Me
  ans = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

 If ans = vbYes Then
  tiekejoIvedimas.Show

  Else
  Sheets("važtaražtis").Select
  End If

End Sub
```

What should I alter to update the whole row?

Comment: Have you stepped through (you can remove the on error lines)? Can't immediately see anything assuming the value is found.

Comment: @SJR I'll try to remove them. What do you mean by "Can't inmediately see anything assuming the value is found"?

Comment: I assume the Find finds something if column A works? Try replacing one of the textbox values with a hardcoded value and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @SJR yes the find is working as intended it gets the value of the cell and then the row number. It works with hardcoded value. I've tryed to remove Me. Infront of the variable, but it didn't do anything. Also as it changes the first cell in a row it seems that the code partially works, it only doesn't change the rest of the cell.

Comment: If it works with hardcoded values then the issue is with the textboxes. Are they are on the same form as the button?

Comment: @SJR yes they are on the same UserForm.

Comment: You'll need to some debugging then.

Comment: Any suggeations how to do it? Maybe passing the values to a MsgBox?

Comment: Step through? Hard to be specific without knowing anything about your exact set up.